# Footer text and social media icon is not showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing making a multi-column website, almost finished, but I have a problem - the footer text on the bottom of the page and the social media icon is not showing. I tried taking a look without the css file linked and the social media icon shows up as a broken image (pretty much I referenced it correctly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Your description goes here">
        <meta name="keywords" content="one, two, three">

        <title>Relaxr</title>

        <!-- external CSS link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainColumn">
            <header>
                <h1>Relaxr</h1>
                <h2>Get piece of mind with a single tap</h2>
            </header>

        <span>
            <button id="getButton">Get it Now</button>
        </span>
        </div>

        <div id="secondColumn">
            <header>
                <h1>Benefits</h1>
                <p>The perfect personal assistant. Relaxr does your job<br>for you so you can enjoy life as it is meant to be.</p>
                <ul class="benefitss">
                    <li>Schedule meetings for you</li>
                    <li>Excel automation to complete your <br>work for you</li>
                    <li>Responds to e-mails on your behalf</li>
                    <li>Does all yor work for you with our<br>revolutionary technology</li>
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="thirdColumn">
            <src="../images/testimonial_bg.jpg">
            <p class="herWords">“Relaxr changed my life. I’ve been able<br> to travel the world, spend limited time<br> working and my boss keeps thanking<br>me for crushing work.”</p>
            <p class="name">- Amanda, Intuit</p>
        </div>

        <div id="fourthColumn">
            <button id="signupButton">Sign Up Now!</button>
        </div>

        <div id="fifthColumn">
            <p>Relaxr</p>
        </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <img src="../images/twitter.png">
                <p>Copyright 2015. Relaxr.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

AND HERE IS MY CSS FILE:

```
/******************************************
/* SETUP
/*******************************************/

/* Box Model Hack */
* {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firexfox */
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
     box-sizing: border-box; /* IE */
}

/* Clear fix hack */
.clearfix:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px; /* note the padding around a right floated image */
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0; /* note the padding around a left floated image */
}

/******************************************
/* BASE STYLES
/*******************************************/

body {
     color: #000;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 1.4;
     font-family: Open Sans;
     background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     background-size: cover;
}


/******************************************
/* LAYOUT
/*******************************************/

/*MAIN COLUMN*/

#mainColumn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainColumn h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 80%
}

#mainColumn h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  height: 40%;
}

/*GET IT NOW BUTTON*/
#getButton {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto'; sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 30px;
  width: 135px;
}

/*SECOND COLUMN*/

#secondColumn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: white;
}

#secondColumn h1 {
  padding-left: 65px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  color: navy;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#secondColumn p {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  color: navy;
}

.benefitss {
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.benefitss li{
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  color: navy;
} 

/*THIRD COLUMN*/
#thirdColumn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

#thirdColumn .herWords {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

#thirdColumn .name {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

/*FOURTH COLUMN*/
#fourthColumn {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

/*SIGN UP BUTTON*/
#signupButton {
  background-color: #000040;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto'; sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 43.5%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#fifthColumn {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
}

#fifthColumn p {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

/*FOOTER TEXT*/

#footer p {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 11%;
}
```

This is what needs to appear:

https://s31.postimg.org/be6k7pumz/Screen_Shot_2016_06_14_at_4_54_37_PM.png

However, only "Relaxr" shows up in the last column. Anyone know what the problem may be? Thanks.

Comment: i clicked at link and it's not working

Comment: Just updated the link!

Comment: There is an extra `</div>` right before the closing `</body>`. Remove it and all should work.

Comment: Hmm is that the only problem? Tried removing the extra </div> and refreshed the page but still does not appear...strange

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "<img>" reference to the HTML.  There's no additional "</div>", but you must fix the img tag.  Here's what I was able to find:

```
<div id="thirdColumn">
    <src="../images/testimonial_bg.jpg">
```

You should have the following:

```
<div id="thirdColumn">
    <img src="../images/testimonial_bg.jpg" />
```

Comment: The reason why I left out the <img> for that was because for that picture, there was a broken image icon on the left side of the picture and getting rid of it resolved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

`#fifthColumn` has `position: absolute`. This most likely causes it to overlap/hide `#footer`, which follows below it (absolute positioned elements don't take any space in the document flow, they overlap whatever is there...). Set `position` to `relative` to check this...